# Laurent Series - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

I want to obtain the Laurent series around the origin of:

$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z^2 \sinh z}$$
My plan is to obtain first the laurent series of: $f(z) = \frac{1}{\sinh z}$ and then divide the terms by $z^2$

So I know that: $\frac{1}{\sinh z} = \ln(z + \sqrt{1+z^2}) = \ln(\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} + 1) +\ln(\sqrt{1+z^2}) = \ln(\frac{z}{\sqrt{1+z^2}} + 1) +\frac{1}{2}\ln(1+z^2)$

using 
$ \ln(z+1) = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} (-1)^{n-1} \frac{z^n}{n}$

I tried to use this series and write:
$\frac{1}{\sinh z} = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \frac{z^n}{(\sqrt{1+z^2})^{n/2}}+ \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n} \frac{z^2n}{2}$

but by doing this I dont obtain the right answer, which is: 
[image]

Comment: $\sinh(z)=\ln(z+\sqrt{1+z^2})$ ? This is wrong ! $1/\sinh(z)=\frac{2}{e^z-e^{-z}}.$

Comment: This answer is not correct for your expression.

Comment: I saw that: $sinh^{-1}z = ln(z+\sqrt(z^2+1))$, could it be that $sinh^{-1}z $is the inverse function instead of the $\frac{1}{sinh z}$

Comment: Yes, the inverse function $\operatorname{arsinh}(z)=\ln(z+\sqrt{z^2+1})$. Not to be confused with $1/\sinh z$.

Comment: Also, you are not allowed to have expressions like $(\sqrt{1+z^2})^{n/2}$ in the answer. Every term should be of the form $z^n$ for $n \in \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Using $\sinh z=\dfrac{e^z-e^{-z}}{2}$ with $e^z=\sum_{n=0}\dfrac{z^n}{n!}$ is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

It's the *inverse* of the hyperbolic sine that has that expression (yet another reason to write the inverse as $\arg\sinh{z}$). $1/\sinh{z}=\operatorname{csch}{z}$ is
$$ \frac{2}{e^z-e^{-z}} = 2\left( 2z+\frac{2}{3!}z^3 + \frac{2}{5!}z^5 + \dotsb \right)^{-1}, $$
and then take out a factor of $z$ and use the binomial expansion of $(1+w)^{-1}$.